# Error accessing UIImage from iphone but not from Xcode simulator

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

I've been having some trouble understanding this bug/error I keep getting when I  try to upload a picture when using `UIImagePickerController`. I'm following this tutorial by [raywenderlich.com (link)](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2)

I've also setup the iOS 10 Privacy Settings.

This is the error code, I only get this error when I run the app on my physical iPhone, on the Xcode sim the app works fine and uploads pictures perfectly.

```
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
[14875:2893865] Body file is unreachable: /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/122APPLE/IMG_2468.JPG
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_2468.JPG” couldn’t           
be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo=
{NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/122APPLE/IMG_2468.JPG, 
NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/122APPLE/IMG_2468.JPG,  
NSUnderlyingError=0x174642040 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 
"Operation not permitted"}}
Error uploading photo: An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.
```

This is the code i'm using to get the Image from photoLibrary

```
extension KalamViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)

    // 1
    if let photoReferenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        // Handle picking a Photo from the Photo Library
        // 2
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [photoReferenceUrl], options: nil)
        let asset = assets.firstObject

        // 3
        if let key = sendPhotoMessage() {
            // 4
            asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
                let imageFileURL = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL

                // 5
                let path = "\(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000))/\(photoReferenceUrl.lastPathComponent)"

                // 6
                self.storageRef.child(path).putFile(imageFileURL!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error uploading photo: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    // 7
                    self.setImageURL(self.storageRef.child((metadata?.path)!).description, forPhotoMessageWithKey: key)
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        // Handle picking a Photo from the Camera - TODO
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever had success uploading from the filesystem like this, so instead I just do it in memory:

```
// pragma mark - UIImagePickerDelegate overrides
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

  // Get local file URLs
  guard let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
  let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

  // Get a reference to the location where we'll store our photos
  let photosRef = storage.reference().child("chat_photos")

  // Get a reference to store the file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
  let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(NSUUID().UUIDString).png")

  // Upload file to Firebase Storage
  let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
  metadata.contentType = "image/png"
  photoRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
    // Upload successful!
  }

  // Clean up picker
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```